# How to Calculate difference between hours when the cells contain date in date format? And there are some conditions too

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Need difference between Created & Closed In Hours along with below

1. The TAT hour to be calculated between 9:00 am to 09:00 pm which is working hours, if created time us 09 pm then it should be considered from next day 9 am.
2. Sunday is Holiday

I have tried:- `=Created-Closed Date`, but don't know how to exclude Sunday and  calculate only shift hours.

[image]

Comment: You can use functions like `=IF(HOUR(C3)<9,9,IF(HOUR(C3)>18,9,HOUR(C3)))` to give the Hour for one cell in Integer format,  similarly for the second cell. And then subract both for to get the working hours.

Comment: Hey Dude! This is not the correct answer, there are some conditions too. please help me to get exact answer if you can.

Comment: I am not saying it's the correct answer, I just gave you a hint so that you can proceed in the right direction. I don't think this community is to give you complete solutions to your problems.

Comment: Oh! I'm sorry, anyway thanks for it. i have tried this too which is giving me a same answer which i have already captured in "Difference" row. Let's see who will be answering it with exact formula.

Comment: See, I have already tried function to get small hint before you gave me. but it doesn't  work for the 3rd one giving wrong answer.                                                 "=IF(VALUE(TEXT(Z3,"HH.MM"))<9,TEXT(Z3,"DD-MMM-YY")&" 09:00:00",IF(VALUE(TEXT(Z3,"HH.MM"))>21,TEXT(Z3,"DD-MMM-YY")&" 21:00:00",TEXT(Z3,"DD-MMM-YY HH:MM:SS")))"

Comment: @Regis you should put those tries into your original question, so people don't have to trawl through comments to follow what you have done or not.. You may find reding this useful : https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Okay, will make Sure from next time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes! Finally Self Got Answer For it.

Here is that

**=(NETWORKDAYS(A2,B2)-1)*("21:00:00"-"09:00:00")
+IF(NETWORKDAYS(B2,B2),MEDIAN(MOD(B2,1),"21:00:00","09:00:00"),"21:00:00")
-MEDIAN(NETWORKDAYS(A2,A2)*MOD(A2,1),"21:00:00","09:00:00")**

Comment: This is a brilliant answer

Comment: Yep! Thanks Lot Mastro !